# Alter message in Gerrit code review

Tags: git, github, repository, gerrit

I've commited a branch to gerrit. Moderators have already approved my code but not merged it yet into the main repository. I tried altering the message on my commit but I keep getting strange errors. Here's what I've done:

1) git checkout FETCH_HEAD     (to checkout the latest changes to a branch, I had to run repo sync after I commited my changes which undid my changes so had to fetch and checkout to get my changes back)

2) git commit --amend
    *opens a text editor and I changed my message there

3) repo upload

When I try #3, it gives me this message: "no branches ready for upload"

I thought my doing a checkout that my branch would be called FETCH_HEAD? Now, do I need to run the repo start   command again? Will this cause a new entry in the gerrit review system or will it just add a new patch? I don't want the moderators to have to think that I altered the files, thereby having them review everything again./ I just want to change the commit message, nothing else.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `repo upload` requires a tracked branch. When I had this problem, I switched back to the "master" branch and merged my changes into it.  I was able to do the `repo upload` from there.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are missing is the --track option while creating a new branch. Your branch is being created but not being tracked for upload. use repo start as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout FETCH_HEAD` doesn't create a branch - instead, it puts your client into a "detached HEAD" state. You need to manually create a branch (with `git checkout -b <branchname>`) if you want one.

Comment: Just tried that - thanks. But still getting the same message: "no branches ready for upload". How do I tell it to upload the new branch I created?